# neo4j query conversion to use in function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have such query, which normally accepts one argument in `{}` brackets.

```
MATCH (pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(next:Person)
  WHERE (:Queue {name: 'A'}) -[:queue_person]-> (pr)
  RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

I want to pass as `Queue name` several possible arguments instead of one, e.g. `{name: 'A' or name: 'B'}`. So I want to have people and their successors from many queues. Queues are also connected one to another.
But such query is not possible and throws exception:

```
MATCH (pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(next:Person)
  WHERE (:Queue {name: 'A' or name: 'B'}) -[:queue_person]-> (pr)
  RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

Instead of above, works sth like this:

```
MATCH (q:Queue)-[:queue_person]->(pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(:next:Person)
  WHERE q.name in ['A','B']
  RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

But I would like to use `(pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(next:Person)` instead of `(q:Queue)-[:queue_person]->(pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(:next:Person)` because somehow it spoil person order so as a result I do not have:

A B

B C

C D

D E ...

It is disturbed somehow because of `queue` in match clause.

Is it possible to pass arguments, in second line, in where clause and keep also there relation between queue and person `-[:queue_person]-> (pr)` like in below not working snippet query?

```
WHERE (:Queue {name in ['A','B']) -[:queue_person]-> (pr)
```

Comment: FYI Cosmos DB's graph API is Gremlin-based, not Cypher-based. I untagged Cosmos DB, accordingly, and added the Cypher tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem of this query in your question

```
MATCH (q:Queue)-[:queue_person]->(pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(:next:Person)
WHERE q.name in ['A','B']
RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

is in this : `(:next:Person)`. and you just need to change to `(next:Person)`

But if it is not , you can use UNWIND :

```
      UNWIND ["A", "B"] AS name
      MATCH (pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(next:Person)
      WHERE (:Queue {name: name}) -[:queue_person]-> (pr)
      RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear how the order is different with

```
MATCH (q:Queue)-[:queue_person]->(pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(:next:Person)
WHERE q.name in ['A','B']
RETURN pr.name, next.name
```

It is hard to tell from the response you shared.

Another way to write it would be

```
MATCH (q:Queue)
WHERE q.name in ['A','B']
WITH q
MATCH (pr:Person)-[:person_successor]->(next:Person)
WHERE (q)-[:queue_person]->(pr)
RETURN pr.name, next.name
```